# laravel 5.4 webpack.mix.js and socket.io include errors

Tags: node.js, socket.io, laravel-5.4

I'm trying to use socket.io.

1) `npm install express ioredis socket.io --save` - ok.

2)my `socket.js:`

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var Redis = require('ioredis');
var fs = require('fs');
var redis = new Redis();
redis.subscribe('notification-channel', function(err, count) {
});
redis.on('message', function(channel, message) {
    console.log('Message Recieved: ' + message);
    message = JSON.parse(message);
    io.emit(channel + ':' + message.event, message.data);
});
http.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('Listening on Port 3000');
});
```

3) `npm run dev` results:

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ssxXI.png)

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K3kb9.png)

How to fix it? Thanks.

Comment: Please do not post images of text. Instead copy and paste the text into the question for better searchability, protection against dead image URLs, and to allow others to easily copy the relevant text.

Comment: It looks like you don't have `fs` installed.  You could try installing it using the code that is in the error "To install it, you can run: npm install --save fs". I'm not saying this will solve the problem but it's worth a go.

Comment: It did not work.

Comment: Make sure you are using the latest versions of Node and NPM as the version you are using may be out of date - you can check your version with `npm -v` and `node -v`

Comment: node v6.11.0, npm -v 5.1.0.